# Excel VBA - Replacing SUBTOTAL Function with a different Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel VBA that uses the Range Subtotal Function in VBA. Everything is fine, but what I need to do on some of the columns is to replace the Subtotal formula on a few columns with a different formula.

The reason why I need to do it this way is because on the other columns I need the subtotal result before I can carry out a different calculation.

I have tried using Replace but my new formula isn't showing.

I want to do

```
Selection.Replace What:="SUBTOTAL(9", Replacement:="RC[-1]/RC[-2]", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

How do I get my new formula in?

Comment: what is an example of the original formula, and what is an example of what you want the new formula to be?

Comment: All of the code is VBA, but the SUBTOTAL simply totals up some values in a column by a group. The formula I want to put into a column takes the subtotal result from Column C and divides it by the subtotal result from Column B

Comment: However, this new formula needs to be added to every group by. So, it is not just to a couple of rows. It could be for any number of groups

Comment: Understand, but replacing "SUBTOTAL(9" with "RC[-1]/RC-2]" will not return a valid formula. Understanding it varies, If you provide a sample of one of the original formulas and its expected result, then I can better understand what the formula needs to be

Comment: Ok, the formula I want to put in as an example is = C133/B133. That's it

Comment: You see I don't want to lose my formatting with the Range Subtotal function as this could potentially mess up the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `Replace` on a cell with a formula, I don't believe the replace is allowed if the result is not a valid formula. Given the format of `SUBTOTAL` your original formula would be something like

`=SUBTOTAL(9,C100:C150)`

and your replacement would result in

`=RC[-1]/RC[-2],C100:C150)`

which is not a valid formula

If i understand correctly you want something like this

`=SUBTOTAL(9,C100:C150)`

to become this

`=RC[-1]/RC[-2]`

To do that, you can use `Find` to search the selected cell to see if "SUBTOTAL(9" is in the formula. If it is, then you replace the entire formula with your desired formula. See the example below

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim searchResult As Range

Set myRange = Selection
Set searchResult = myRange.Find(What:="SUBTOTAL(9", LookIn:=xlFormulas)

Do While Not searchResult Is Nothing
    searchResult.Formula = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
    Set searchResult = myRange.FindNext(searchResult)
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a try and let you know how I get on

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. After studying the code, it will place the formula in every row of the column. It only needs to be in the row of the column where the subtotals are for each group.

Comment: Ok, I made the assumption there was only one cell selected. I've updated the code to find every cell in the selected range that has "SUBTOTAL(9" in the formula, and replace it with the formula.